# Adding headers to Jetty in Wiremock

Tags: jetty, wiremock

I'm running into CORS issues using the Wiremock standalone jar. I call my mock service using jQuery ajax. Is it possible to add the required "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header when starting up the server?

Answer (score 4):

I got it to work by adding an options.json file in my mappings folder for the CORS preflight request

```
{
  "request" : {
    "url" : "/myurl",
    "method" : "OPTIONS"    
  },
  "response" : {
    "status" : 200,
    "headers" : {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "http://myorigin",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "accept, content-type",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST"
    }
  }
}
```

and all my other mappings look like this

```
{
  "request" : {
    "urlPattern" : "/myurl",
    "method" : "POST",
    "bodyPatterns" : [ {
      "equalToJson" : "{\"foo\":0}",
      "jsonCompareMode" : "LENIENT"
    } ]
  },
  "response" : {
    "status" : 200,
    "bodyFileName" : "body-file.json",
    "headers" : {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*"
    }
  }
}
```

hope it helps

Comment: @user372132- Can you give little more detail explanation about url,Access-Control-Allow-Origin?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make it work, with **wiremock** in standalone just adding  `enable-stub-cors` flag.

```
java -jar wiremock-standalone-2.27.2.jar --enable-stub-cors
```